# Why i cannot allocate a a memory using a a base class type pointing to a derived class pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, memory

```
class a
{
    int var;
}
class b :public a
{
    int var2,var3;
}

int main()
{
    a *poi;
    poi=new b;
    //b *poi2;
    //poi2=new a;
    return 0
}
```

In above code,i was able to allocate a memory using a derived class type pointing to a base class pointer variable.
i.e, `a *poi=new b;`
But i was not able to allocate a memory using a  a base class type pointing to a derived class pointer.
i.e. `b *poi=new a;`

Why the following memory allocation is not possible?
What is the logic behind it?

Comment: If you have a pointer to a `b` object, that object shouldn't be half-constructed.

Comment: Think about it: if `b *poi = new a;` was legal, what should `poi->var2++;` do?

Answer (score 4):

That's not about memory allocation but about inheritance.

```
Fruit* f = new Apple
```

works well, but

```
Apple* a = new Fruit
```

would give you a incomplete apple, or even a banana, so compiler doesn't allow you doing that.

Both pointers have same size, and you could use a [unsafe static cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)  to store a fruit pointer into a apple pointer, but you should avoid doing that

Comment: It is just a pointer that will hold only address... So we no need to bother about incomplete apple or banana.... It just points the address of the class.

Comment: Yes, both variable will hold just a pointer, an `sizeof(f)==sizeof(a)`, usually 8 or 4

Comment: Thats what am asking  "sizeof(f)==sizeof(a)". So why we cant map to apple or banana or even fruit. It is possible na.. is  standard says about it.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really have anything to do with the memory allocation. It is simply that the first conversion is a valid implicit conversion (from derived class pointer to base pointer), but the second is not (from base class pointer to derived pointer):

> *§4.10/3 [conv.ptr]* A prvalue of type “pointer to cv D”, where D is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv B”, where B is a base class (Clause 10) of D.

The reason for this is that polymorphism represents an *is-a* relationship. A `b` *is an* `a`, but an `a` is not a `b`. Therefore, you can have an `a` pointer pointing at a `b`, because the object it's pointing at is a valid `a` object. However, you can't have a `b` pointer pointing at an `a`, because an `a` object is not necessarily a valid `b` object.

Comment: Well, it _also_ has to do with memory allocation, since `sizeof(b) > sizeof(a)`. Thus, by doing the allocation "the wrong way around", you invoke UB by "legally" accessing unallocated memory when reading `var2` or `var3`, past the end of the `a` object.

Comment: @Damon The allocation is not "the wrong way round" though - it's the conversion. If that conversion were allowed, the UB would only start when you attempt to access the object.

Answer (score 1):

here `a *poi;` `poi=new b;` is valid because `poi` has the reference of `var` and the object of `b` also has the variable `var` because of inheritance. which is a valid reference.

in case of `b *poi2;` `poi2=new a;`  `poi2` also can have reference of `var2` and `var3` but object of `a` doesn't contain `var2` and `var3`. which leads to an invalid reference.
I mean `poi2->var2` is a valid statement but there is no `var2` if compiler allow  `poi2=new a;` then `poi2->var2` will point to an invalid memory segment.